# Compare element values in a array and fetch the biggest value elements inside the Parent element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to create a XSLT in 1.0.PLease find below a sample xml. The requirement is to get the biggest value1 field from all 3 and display the tags inside them.

Request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetTestValues xmlns="http://www.test.com/GetTestValues">
  <TestSample>
    <Test>
      <value1>10000</value1>
      <value2>2016-01-28</value2>
      <value3>2017-12-10T01:36:12.403+00:00</value3>
      <value4>US</value4>
      <value5>true</value5>
    </Test>
    <Test>
      <value1>30000</value1>
      <value2>2019-01-28</value2>
      <value3>2019-01-28T18:04:13.763+00:00</value3>
      <value4>Canada</value4>
      <value5>false</value5>
    </Test>
    <Test>
      <value1>50000</value1>
      <value2>2019-01-28</value2>
      <value3>2019-01-28T18:04:13.763+00:00</value3>
      <value4>Canada</value4>
      <value5>false</value5>
    </Test>
  </TestSample>
</GetTestValues>
```

Expected Response after transformation:

Request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetTestValues xmlns="http://www.test.com/GetTestValues">
  <TestSample>
    <Test>
      <value1>50000</value1>
      <value2>2019-01-28</value2>
      <value3>2019-01-28T18:04:13.763+00:00</value3>
      <value4>Canada</value4>
      <value5>false</value5>
    </Test>
  </TestSample>
</GetTestValues>
```

I tried to put foreach and it is displaying everything. Not sure how to compare the get the great value.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns0:GetTestValues/ns0:TestSample/ns0:Test">
  <ns0:value1>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:value1"/>
  </ns0:value1>
  <ns0:value2>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:value2"/>
  </ns0:value2>
  <ns0:value3>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:value3"/>
  </ns0:value3>
  <ns0:value4>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:value4"/>
  </ns0:value4>
  <ns0:value5>
    <xsl:value-of select="ns0:value5"/>
  </ns0:value5>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Edit your question to make it legible.

Comment: I don't see where grouping comes into this. To get the node with the maximum value (in XSLT 1.0) you need to sort the nodes by value and take the first (or the last) node - see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848387/3016153 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28359107/3016153.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not really readable. The easiest way to produce readable code on StackOverflow is to use a row of three back-ticks to start and end each of your code blocks. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this stylesheet, I iterate over the set of `Test` elements, in descending order of their `value1` child elements (so that the first `Test` element has the highest `value1`). Inside the `for-each` I check the current position of the iteration, and if it's `1` then I copy the current `Test` element; the other `Test` elements are simply ignored.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/GetTestValues">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Select only the Test child whose value1 is greatest -->
    <xsl:template match="test:TestSample">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- iterate over the test child elements, in descending order of value1 -->
            <xsl:for-each select="test:Test">
                <xsl:sort select="test:value1" order="descending"/>
                <!-- copy the test element if it's the first (has the highest value1) -->
                <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```